# Unable to allocate seems to be unsolvable

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

i am trying to make a text processor with 320MB text as data

this is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
from itertools import chain
import dask.array as da
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
file_path ="train.text"
file = open(file_path,'r',encoding='utf-8')#using encoding ='utf-8' cuz the text is in persian
sentences = []
for f in file:
    sentences.append(f)
tokenizer = tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(sentences)
total_word = len(tokenizer.word_index)
input_sentences =[]
word_index = tokenizer.word_index
for i in sentences:
    i=i.strip()
    k = i.split(" ")
    token_list = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(k)
    n = len(k)
    for j in range(2,n):
        n_gram_sequences = token_list[:j]
        n_gram_sequences = list(chain.from_iterable(n_gram_sequences))
        input_sentences.append(n_gram_sequences)
```

Everything is working fine, but when I want to pad the sequence I get this error:

```
padded = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(input_sentences,maxlen=max_squence_length,padding='pre')


Unable to allocate 121. GiB for an array with shape (33971923, 958) and data type int32
```

(note that I am using vscode and Windows10)
I tried to change the padding with a for loop :

```
for i in range(1,100):
    padded = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(input_sentences[int(total_sentences*(i-1)/100):int(total_sentences*(i)/100)],maxlen=max_squence_length,padding='pre')
```

it was fine but when I wanted to use keras-to_categorical i get this error:

```
xs, labels= padded[:,:-1],padded[:,-1]
ys = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(labels,total_word)
```

Changing "managing paging file size" did not work for me too:( :
[image]

Someone said using GPU will help but i still have the error!

Can you explain what the error is and how to solve it please?

Comment: It does not make sense to encode a dataset so it grows to 121GB, you cannot hold that in memory, you probably need to use a generator so encoding is on the fly, only when needed.

Comment: Thanks, but idk how to use a generator would you explain more please?